# Why does resolve.conf always return 192.168.1.1?

Tags: macos, dns

I set different DNS servers on my wireless router from 192.168.1.1 but when I check for which DNS servers are being used, it returns 192.168.1.1. Why does it not return the DNS addresses I set on the router?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those are the DNS servers the router uses. It publishes *itself* as a DNS server into your LAN.

Comment: So how can I check if it's using the DNS servers I set?